# Shutdown is slow, always waiting 2 minutes for gvfsd-fuse to terminate

Tags: systemd, opensuse, shutdown, gvfs

My desktop is using OpenSuse 15.1 with latest updates, systemd 234-lp151.26.16.1, gvfs 1.34.2.1-lp151.6.3.1.

Since a while (I cannot remember exactly when it started) a system shutdown takes at least 2 minutes to complete.
When I hit `ESC` at the splash screen, I see systemd is waiting for a User Manager job to finish and, after some digging, I figured out that it is this process:

`/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs -f -o big_writes`

I did some research and discovered that this is automatically started by programs like Firefox and Thunderbird (and others).
I also verified that:

- If I boot and don't use such programs, the shutdown is fast;
- If I logout and use the console to kill those user processes, the shutdown is fast;
- Other user accounts are affected too, only if they use the mentioned programs.

I configured `systemd` with: `KillUserProcesses=yes`, but it does not help as it seems those processes still take 2 minutes to be terminate after the logout.

Furthermore, on the same machine I can also boot Ubuntu-mate (18.04 LTS) from a separate SSD and it shows the same symptoms.

How do I figure out what's causing the 2 minutes delay ?

Edit: perhaps it's worth mentioning that once I logout, I cannot log back in again because I get a dialog "Could not sync with Dbus". I need to do a ctrl-Backspace to reset X first.

Comment: some share over Network like (samba, nfs) or somethiing other in this direction?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The problem is quite easy to reproduce. I just need to start Firefox or Thunderbird and then close them. If I don't, the extra mount is not there and shutdown is fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FUSE has a dedicated command `fusermount` for undoing FUSE mounts. At least on Debian 10, it has SUID root set by default.

So you might add `fusermount -u /run/user/$(id -u)/gvfs` to the script that gets executed at GUI logout (e.g. `$HOME/.kde/shutdown/gvfs-workaround.sh` on older KDE, or `$HOME/.config/plasma-workspace/shutdown/gvfs-workaround.sh` on KDE Plasma Desktop).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This not only solves the shutdown delay, but I can now immediately log back in without errors.
Since it seems  more a matter of "cleaning up", I wonder why this is not included in the logout process by default, or at least have a configuration option to choose.

Comment: I think `gvfs` is (or originally was) a GNOME desktop component, so it's not as well integrated with KDE as it could be ("kioslaves" are KDE's answer to a similar need). Firefox and Thunderbird are both built as GNOME applications, so they may trigger some GNOME-specific services to start up. The fact that `gvfsd-fuse` is not getting properly shut down with KDE would certainly be worth sending in a bug report, though.

Comment: I agree, it will be challenging to figure out where to lodge that bug report though. KDE ? systemd ? openSuse ? FUSE ? I will make an attempt...

Comment: "bug" reported and linked to similar ones: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=422322

Answer (score 1):

The delay could be caused by several factors most of them being user processes or systemd processes.

If you are using `KDE` which is the default desktop environment for Open SUSE, try the script below, which terminates the user manager process on exit. It worked for me.

Add the script to `$HOME/.kde/shutdown`

`#! /bin/sh -
 pulseaudio --kill
 systemctl --user exit
exit`

Please leave some feedback if this workode for you or not, Thank you.

Comment: How do you know that OP is using KDE?

Comment: As a matter of fact, I do use KDE. Still.. that script is merely a workaround as it simply moves the problem, making the logout wait 2 minutes. Running them in the background is no solution either as I am pretty sure it will get messy if I login back in again.

Comment: What would work is to do a 'umount /run/user/1000/gvfs' inside such a script, but it needs to be run as root, so...

Comment: On Debian 10, using KDE Plasma Desktop, a similar workaround applies, but the script should be placed in `$HOME/.config/plasma-workspace/shutdown/` instead.